# What's the proper way to write an Avro IDL for a Kafka topic listening to multiple events?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, avro-tools

We plan to use a single topic in Kafka where we will publish events related to a domain. The IDL definition will be something like:

```
protocol KafkaTopic {

   record EventA {
      int anIntHappened;
   }

   record EventB {
      string aStringHappened;
   }
}
```

So we have a single channel and a multiplicity of types flowing through that channel. All the encoding is being done using `SpecificRecordBase` derived classes.

I think that now we have several options:

- Encode each single message with its associated schema. The drawback is that we are introducing an overhead for each message.
- Create a union type `KafkaTopicMessage` within the IDL definition and send messages without schema. Then I don't know what will happen with compiled clients with older schemas. Hopefully nothing wrong but this extra wrapping in a union seems unnatural to me but maybe it is right in this context.
- Let clients pick several schemas they are interested in and [create the union schema](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.html#createUnion(java.util.List)) on consumer side. Producers will send plain schemas without any union at all. I don't even know if this can work.

So the questions is, what are common patterns when using Avro encoding in conjunction with Kafka topic messages?